# How to create derived mongodb field that updates implicitly on another filed update?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to create a "calculated" or "derived" filed that updates implicitly on a change of some other filed?

Imagine there are two fields `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and I want to have `{"c": 3}` with value `c = a + b` that updates implicitly on a change `a` or `b` and (optionally) disappears if `a` or `b` removed.

Answer (score 0):

Via mongo shell there is nothing about it.
But if you use Mongo Atlas, there are Triggers: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/index.html
If you are accessing MongoDB through a programming language, I think you can use the Change Streams to do this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams